# c3.js X-Axis String Value Javascript error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am setting values to a simple c3.js bar chart by javascript. Here is how I am setting the values

```
var values={  x : 'x', 
type: "bar", 
columns: [['x', data_0x,data_1x,data_2x,data_3x,data_4x] ,
["% of Employees",data_0y,data_1y,data_2y,data_3y,data_4y]]}
```

While generating the chart, the following is my code

```
var chart = new c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chartContainer',
        data: values,
        axis: {x: {type: 'category'}}
});
```

When **data_0x, data_1x** etc are numerical values, the chart comes out perfect.

However when these are string values like 'a', 'b' etc, I am getting the following javascript errors

```
d3.v3.min.js:670 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0)".attrFunction @ d3.v3.min.js:670
d3.v3.min.js:670 Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".attrFunction @ d3.v3.min.js:670
d3.v3.min.js:670 Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The shared pieces of code are working fine, even when changing the x-values to a string. Maybe there is a case that one of your x-value is being unassigned?